# When adding to or removing from an ArrayCollection, does it always produce an ADD or REMOVE CollectionEvent?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, collections

I was about to add an event listener to one of my ArrayCollections, like so:

```
m_acElements.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE,
        onCollectionChange);
```

While starting to write the onCollectionChange function, I referred to the API reference concerning [CollectionEvent.kind](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CollectionEvent.html#kind), which states:

```
"Indicates the kind of event that occurred. The property value can be one of the
values in the CollectionEventKind class, or null, which indicates that the kind
is unknown."
```

This is scary.  There's not a whole heck of a lot being said there about *when* the kind is unknown, and it's not immediately obvious while looking around in other places for an indication.

I'm not doing anything exotic here.  Is there some sort of guarantee then that non-error raising calls to AddItem and AddItemAt will produce an ADD event, and that removeAll and removeItemAt will produce a REMOVE event?  Or is this just not completely reliable?

I supposed I could override those methods in a subclass if necessary, but I'd rather just be told that I'm being paranoid.  Plus I just want to have a general idea of when to watch out for this with CollectionEvents.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overreacting here. It's just Adobe being overly detailed with their code documentation. If the `kind` is not set or an unknown type occurs, the value is null. This can happen if someone manually dispatches the event, if someone forgets to set the kind, or if someone doesn't extend the event properly. Adobe's documentation is almost always extremely thorough. Very rarely do they not go above and beyond what is expected. This is just them being thorough and covering all bases. If there was a chance of Adobe's code dispatching an event with a different/unknown kind, they would have provided another constant for it (that's just the way Adobe's Flash dev team works)